# How do I add forEach index to arguments of callback function of addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a `forEach` loop that adds an event listener to each checkbox. I want to add to the function called from the callback the index we are at in the loop like this :

```
function handleCheck(e, counter){

    console.log(counter); //This should print the counter
    console.log(e); //this should print the event
    console.log(this); //this should print the checkbox

}

checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox, counter){
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', handleCheck(counter));
});
```

but the arguments are not passed properly .. can you tell me what is the thing I misunderstanding ?

Comment: @cyrix this binding gives me an error of `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>`

Comment: Whoops, the bind should't be there. Just use: `addEventListener('click', function(e) { handleCheck(e, counter) })`. I deleted my comment, cause i can't edit it anymore.

Comment: @cyrix then that will help solve passing the event and the counter but still the "this" will reference to the window instead of the checkbox

Comment: If you want `this` to point to the checkox you can use `handleCheck.apply(this, e, counter)`

Comment: @cyrix yes, it worked like that with call instead of apply .. thank u

Comment: I ment to write `apply(this, [e, counter])` but call fits in as well :P

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
function handleCheck(e, counter, thisObj){

    console.log(counter); //This should print the counter
    console.log(e); //this should print the event
    console.log(thisObj); //this should print the checkbox

}
var chkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxesArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<chkboxes.length; i++){
 checkboxesArray[i] = chkboxes[i].outerHTML;
}
checkboxesArray.forEach(function(checkbox, index) {
    chkboxes[index].addEventListener('click', function (index) {
        return function (e) {
            handleCheck(e.type, index, this);
        }
    }(index));
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="1"/>Check box 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="2"/>Check box 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="3"/>Check box 3<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over `counter` and return a function which calls `handleCheck`.

```
checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox, counter) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (counter) {
        return function (e) {
            handleCheck(e, counter);
        }
    }(counter));
});
```